# Split text in multiple HTML elements for different formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need some proper way to split down the **unknown** received text to break it into two HTML elements for different formatting.

For example, we have the text "*Hello Dear World!*" and it should be splited into two parts, "*Hello*" will be the first-line element, like title, and the rest of the text will be the second element, subtitle.

Another example, "*No More Heros Anymore!*", will be differently splitted, two words in the first line and the rest in the second, it's non-sense to set only the word "*No*" as a title, at least the text should have a similar length.

Examples visualized below.

Is there some good practice to do it with JS, considering the character length and number of words?

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
.title-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2vw;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title-box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: orange;
}
.title-box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: orange;
}
.title-box.second,
.title-box.second:before,
.title-box.second:after {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.title {
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-box">
    <div class="title">Hello</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Dear World!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title-box second">
    <div class="title">No More</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Heroes Anymore!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well if you are going to like you say: "considering the character length and number of words?", consider length and number, then take that logic and write JS for it... I don't see the problem in your question, nether the explanation of rules on splinting.

Comment: Copying my comment from below: The point is that designers often provide some eye candy with Lorem Ipsum text and in many cases text is dynamic/unknown and needs to be broken and formatted differently without any knowledge about. Cannot find anything too much helpful and thought that maybe someone had similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made something pretty cool for you.  I took the input string (I added a `p` of class `demo` with the whole string), broke it up into individual words, then checked if the first word is greater than 3 characters.  If it is greater than 3, then only use the first word in the title and the rest in the subtitle (box 1).

If it's not greater than 3 characters then its a small word like "no" or "the" or something of the like so I then opted to use the first 2 words in the string for the title, then the rest in the subtitle. Check it out!

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("title-box");
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {

  var str = box[i].querySelector(".demo").innerHTML
  var split1 = str.split(" ", 1);
  
  if (split1[0].length > 3){
  var split2 = str.split(" ");
  box[i].querySelector(".title").innerHTML = split2[0];
  split2.shift();
  box[i].querySelector(".subtitle").innerHTML = split2.join(" ");
  }
  
  else{
  var split2 = str.split(" ");
  box[i].querySelector(".title").innerHTML = split2[0] + " " + split2[1];
  split2.shift();
  split2.shift();
  box[i].querySelector(".subtitle").innerHTML = split2.join(" ");
  }
  
  }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
.title-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2vw;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title-box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: orange;
}
.title-box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: orange;
}
.title-box.second,
.title-box.second:before,
.title-box.second:after {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.title {
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
}

.demo {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-box">
   <p class="demo" >Hello Dear World!</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class= "subtitle"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="title-box second">
    <p class="demo">No More Heros Anymore!</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class= "subtitle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I was looking for some more general and neat solution. The point is that designers often provide some eye candy with Lorem Ipsum text and in many cases text is dynamic/unknown and needs to be broken and formatted differently without any knowledge about. Cannot find anything too much helpful and thought that maybe someone had similar problems.

Comment: @swolfish Can you explain more general and neat?  This will take literally any input string and break it appropriately.